# The Hat that Hates Me

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

I don't like being stuck on a web page. Only someone that hates me will lock any possible action.

But whenever I try visit any specific hat on the [main Winter Bash page](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) by a direct URL - that hat will do exactly this: ([example](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/the-stallman))

> [image]

See this little pink X? It won't budge. It ignores my clicks. I am forever stuck with that popover until I close the web page or manually change the URL. (clicking outside the box also won't close it, guess by design)

It happens with all hats, here is [another one for you](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/sock-puppet).

Reproduced with:

- Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m
- Internet Explorer 11
- Firefox 25.0.1

(under Windows 7)

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1679706#1679706

Comment: You're *sooo* behind the times. All us cool kids are playing winterbash-2013.

Comment: @balpha dupe then? ;)

Comment: @Bala what is wrong exactly?

Comment: I think it may just be browser specific. I had this bug with Chrome, but on IE9 didn't have it.

Comment: @hichris123 happens with IE11 and Firefox 25. IE9 only code isn't very good.

Comment: @ShadowWizard are you sure that its isn't a Z-Indexing issue? that would explain quite a bit ;)

Comment: @ehime it's fixed now and no, it wasn't z-index issue. As [balpha said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211829/the-hat-that-hates-me?noredirect=1#comment681267_211832), the click was ignored in the specific case of directly browsing to a hat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working around an issue with Chrome's history API (using [this hack](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/143#issuecomment-6194330)), and I missed one place where I have to do some special handling. Fixed now.

Comment: Cool, weird that I didn't see any JS error though.

Comment: The click was just ignored, there was no error.